# Maximo Anywhere Fetch Domain Data issue

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2(Work Execution App). I have added a domain field in SYNONYM-DOMAIN but I couldn't fetch the data from MAM. New Field AREA (Area Code and Area Desc) which is similar to existing STATUS field (Status code and Status Desc).

From the below code, where "getworktype" query exists. Is it just a name given here or mapped in Maximo..

```
<queryBases id="additionalworktype_queryBases">
                <queryBase id="additionalworktype_queryBase_getworktype" name="getworktype" queryUri="/oslc/os/oslcworktype"/>
            </queryBases>                                   
            <whereClause id="additionalworktype_whereClause"/>
```

Comment: @Mitesh Mistry: Suggest some solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

From that example, the name="getworktype" is not mapping to any underlying query in the Maximo server.

Can you post some more information please about your Synonymdomain resource that's not pulling the new fields?

Comment: I have resolved that issue with proper resource attribute mapping but I need to do multiple value selection in Anywhere.